# How to get JSON after geolocation in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm building a project that finds the geolocation from the browser, then uses the coordinates to get data from the Dark Sky API (https://darksky.net/dev/).

I am able to get the geolocation from the browser, but am having trouble calling the JSON object once I get the geolocation. I understand that getting the geolocation is "asynchronous" and runs at the same time as my other code, and I can't seem to figure out a way around it.

Am I'm doing something wrong? It never seems to runs the: `$.getJSON` part.

All the `#test` htmls are for my reference to see where my code is going wrong. `#test4` never runs, but `#test3` does.

P.S. I've kept the API key hidden for my question, hence the `KEY` characters in the url. The `myJson` variable does concatenate a proper url to retrieve the JSON object.

Any help would be deeply appreciated!

```
var myLat;
var newMyLat;
var myLong;
var newMyLong;
var myJson;
var functionCall;

$(document).ready(function() {

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      myLat = position.coords.latitude;
      myLong = position.coords.longitude;
      newMyLat = parseFloat(myLat).toFixed(4);
      newMyLong = parseFloat(myLong).toFixed(4);

      $("#test1").html("latitude: " + newMyLat + "<br>longitude: " + newMyLong);

      myJson =
        "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/KEY/" +
        newMyLat +
        "," +
        newMyLong;
      $("#test2").html(myJson);

      getJsonData();

    }); // end of getCurrentPosition function
  } // end of navigator.geolocation function
}); // end of document.ready function

function getJsonData() {
  $("#test3").html("getJsonData called");
  $.getJSON(myJson, function(data) {
    $("#test4").html("JSON retrieved");
  }); // end of .getJSON function
} // end of getJsonData function
```

Comment: Read the FAQ for that api. It does not support CORS and you need to use a proxy on your server to keep your key secure.

Comment: Just had a look, you made a good point. I also tried using another API (Open Weather Map), still not working. This project is for an online learning course (FreeCodeCamp) and needs to be done on CodePen, is there anyway to set up that proxy server?

Comment: If willing to expose your key could use a third party proxy service

Comment: Or just create a simple project in heroku or other free host that can be used as proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer that worked for this situation:

I just needed to add `?callback=?` to the end of my JSON url, making it:

```
myJson = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/ee2f66f091ed810afc3bf04adc5fa750/" + myLat + "," + myLong + "?callback=?";
```

Thank you for all the help!